# How to dynamically fill a String[] Array with a File/Database

Tags: java, android

fellow programmers:
So I know how to fill a String[] Array with fixed entries like this:

```
String[] restaurants = new String[] { "McDonalds", "KFC", "Tacos", "Something", "Huh", "WTF"};
```

But thing is:
  -I need to read data from a File or a Database
  -I need a String[] for a ListAdapter
  -I cannot fix the size of the Array, because I don't know the amount of data i'm going to receive

I have been searching in the web about this, but i'm unable to find the answer.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many entries you will need to read, read them into a List and then convert the list to an array when you are done; e.g.

```
    List<String> l = ...
    // read list
    String[] restaurants = l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but when I add List<String> list; it needs to be initialized, how do I do that?

Comment: @CodeKrieger: [List of implementing classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (e.g. l = new ArrayList<String>())

Comment: @CodeKrieger: if you go through the link in my answer there is a very similar example of what you are trying to achieve